# Extremely slow wireless on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless

I am facing extremely slow wireless connection on Ubuntu 14.04. Also the connection is sporadic. Please help me with this. Also, if there is any more information needed do let me know.

Comment: What kind of wireless card do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I had found the link from @samsy to be useful, and had a couple of additional things that I did which helped, but did not cure, the problem:

WICD does not entirely work for me in 14.04 - the wireless will not automatically connect, and WICD seems to be unmaintained

I had improvement in wirless performance by setting the regulatory agency:

```
iw reg get
sudo it reg set US
```

Change your country code as required

Disk scheduling also seems to have helped me.  My install defaulted to 'deadline' for a disk scheduler.  I've changed to cfq for scheduling, and am much happier with overall performance.

To show scheduler:

```
for f in /sys/block/sd?/queue/scheduler; do printf "$f is "; cat $f; done
```

to change scheduler:

```
echo cfq > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```

To change it persistantly, either use the above command in /etc/rc.local, or place it as a kernel option (elevator=cfq) in grub